# org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.xhtml.XHTMLConverter not generating images

Tags: java, html, apache-poi

I am using org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.xhtml.XHTMLConverter class to convert docx to html. Below is my groovy code

```
public Map convert(String wordDocPath, String htmlPath,
        Map conversionParams)
{
    log.info("Converting word file "+wordDocPath)
    try
    {
        ...
        String notificationWorkingFolder = "C:\tomcats\Notification\store\Notification1234"

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(wordDocPath);
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);
        XHTMLOptions options = XHTMLOptions.create().URIResolver(new FileURIResolver(new File(notificationWorkingFolder)));
        File htmlFile = new File(htmlPath);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(htmlFile)
        XHTMLConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);

        log.info("Converted to HTML file "+htmlPath)

        return [success:true,htmlFileName:getFileName(htmlPath)]
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        log.error("Exception :"+e.getMessage(),e)
        return [success:false]
    }

}
```

The above code is converting docx to html successfully, but if docx contains any images it puts `<img src="C:\tomcats\Notification\store\Notification1234\word\media\image1.png">` but do not copy the image to that folder. As a result, when I open html tag, all images appears empty. Am I missing something in code? Is there a way to generate an image srouce link instead of absolute path, like `<img src="http://localhost:8080/webapp/image1.png">`

Comment: I got answer for first question from this link http://www.lychaox.com/java/poi/Word07toHtml.html. I had to add one line of code ` options.setExtractor(new FileImageExtractor(imageFolderFile)); ` to generate images. I need help with second question. Is it possible to generate http links instead of absolute path

Comment: for your second question, define your image file path as virtual directory or alias and replace it with your actual web URL.

Comment: what you are suggesting is search and replace method. Is there way apache poi api itself can handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer for first question from this link lychaox.com/java/poi/Word07toHtml.html. I had to add one line of code `options.setExtractor(new FileImageExtractor(imageFolderFile));` to generate images. 
Second question I resolved by pattern search and replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Even with proper usage, it's worth noting that XHTMLConverter uses XHTMLMapper, which does not process [headers](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/blob/xdocreport-parent-2.0.2/thirdparties-extension/fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.xhtml/src/main/java/fr/opensagres/poi/xwpf/converter/xhtml/internal/XHTMLMapper.java#L535-L541), [footers](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/blob/xdocreport-parent-2.0.2/thirdparties-extension/fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.xhtml/src/main/java/fr/opensagres/poi/xwpf/converter/xhtml/internal/XHTMLMapper.java#L543-L549), or [VML Images](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/blob/xdocreport-parent-2.0.2/thirdparties-extension/fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.xhtml/src/main/java/fr/opensagres/poi/xwpf/converter/xhtml/internal/XHTMLMapper.java#L609-L613). Any images falling into those categories will be lost.

The PDFConverter is more fully featured, but also uses the GPL licensed library, iText.