# Convert .doc with images to .html using xdocreport

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, xdocreport

i am converting doc to html using following code

```
private static final String docName = "This is a test page.docx";
private static final String outputlFolderPath = "C://";
String htmlNamePath = "docHtml1.html";
String zipName="_tmp.zip";
static File docFile = new File(outputlFolderPath+docName);
File zipFile = new File(zipName);

public void ConvertWordToHtml() {
    try {
        InputStream doc = new FileInputStream(new File(outputlFolderPath+docName));
        System.out.println("InputStream"+doc);
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(doc);
        XHTMLOptions options = XHTMLOptions.create(); //.URIResolver(new FileURIResolver(new File("word/media")));;
        String root = "target";
        File imageFolder = new File( root + "/images/" + doc );
        options.setExtractor( new FileImageExtractor( imageFolder ) );
        options.URIResolver( new FileURIResolver( imageFolder ) );
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(htmlPath()));
        XHTMLConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, Exception {
    Convertion cwoWord=new Convertion();
    cwoWord.ConvertWordToHtml();    

}


public String htmlPath(){
    return outputlFolderPath+htmlNamePath;
}

public String zipPath(){
    // d:/_tmp.zip
    return outputlFolderPath+zipName;
}
```

Above code is converting doc to html fine. Issue comes when i try to convert a doc file which has graphics 
like circle (shown in screenshot), In this case, graphics doesn't show into html file.

[image]

Please help me out how can we maintain graphics from doc to html file as well after conversion. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745615/org-apache-poi-xwpf-converter-xhtml-xhtmlconverter-not-generating-images, but in general please note that this functionality is not provided by Apache POI, but rather https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport, unfortunately they use the org.apache namespace which they should not!

Comment: @centic:Thanks for reply,i have already looked at given link,i am able to convert images inside doc, but not the graphics which is attached above

Answer (score 1):

You can embed the images in the html by using the following code:

```
Base64ImageExtractor imageExtractor = new Base64ImageExtractor();
options.setExtractor(imageExtractor);
options.URIResolver(imageExtractor);
```

where Base64ImageExtractor looks like:

```
public class Base64ImageExtractor implements IImageExtractor, IURIResolver {

    private byte[] picture;

    public void extract(String imagePath, byte[] imageData) throws IOException {
        this.picture = imageData;
    }

    private static final String EMBED_IMG_SRC_PREFIX = "data:;base64,";


    public String resolve(String uri) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(picture.length + EMBED_IMG_SRC_PREFIX.length())
                .append(EMBED_IMG_SRC_PREFIX)
                .append(Base64Utility.encode(picture));
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```